# Skein relation, Braids, and Hecke algebra

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

Many knot invariants (e.g. Alexander polynomial, Jones Polynomial,etc) admit a recursive algorithm
based on the so-called [skein relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skein_relation)

But why the skein relation is a natural thing?

People have been dreaming of understanding knot theory via braids. Due to Alexander, each knot could be realized
as the closure of some braid. Markov’s theorem, which roughly says, braids (up to the two types of M-move) are the same
as knots (up to Reidemister move), established a bridge between knot theory and braid theory.

In the perspective of braid theory, the triple of knots in the skein relation is a natural thing: In the local part we are interested in,
a generator $\sigma$, its inverse, and the identity.

We may consider the representation of braid group in some less complicated algebraic objects and  expect  the skein relation to be a natural thing in such representations.

In his [AMS Notices paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyhDl.png)  Jones sketched it a bit.

I wish to see more details. Could knot theory experts help?

Comment: What do you want to understand about knots?  If you get specific about your question, we can likely give a specific answer.  But as written your question reads a bit more like "please write an essay on knots".  A good and bad feature of knot theory is that you can encode many very different kinds of problems in the language.  So one person's motivation to work in the area may be very diffferent than another's.  There are many different tools for studying knots, because there are many different types of knot theory problems.

Comment: From a certain perspective the skein relation is not so natural - I mean, people didn't go out looking for knot invariants satisfying a skein relation! My understanding is that Jones was doing something completely different, noticed that he could use it to define a knot invariant, and then noticed that it satisfied a skein relation. Earlier Alexander defined his polynomial using the fundamental group, and Conway found that it satisfied a skein relation. Afterwards people went looking for polynomials satisfying skein relations and found the most general one (HOMFLY).